# Install package via apt from a live cd to the real system

Tags: debian, apt, live-cd, rescue-disk

I can only boot via live CD and I need to install the Debian package `firmware-linux-nonfree` to my server for it to be able to successfully boot.

How can I do this? Would `chroot` help me ?

Comment: Why don't you install it from USB-stick or whatever during installation?

Comment: My server is in a datacenter and does only boot via live CD, it does boot in emergency mode otherwise. I cannot use a KVM or access the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## First solution :

- You can install driver needed to boot in recovery.
  One things to notice : only `/` is mounted so rememeber that you need to mount other partition such as `/usr` or `/home` if needed
- You need to remount the `/` in read and write mode :
  `mount -o remount,rw /`
- You just have to install your package like you're doing in normal mode.
- Packages installed in the recovery mode do persist in the normal mode.

## Another way to try

- Boot from CD
- Find your HDD with `fdisk -l` or `lsblk`
- Mount it with this command ``mkdir /mnt/hdd && mount /dev/sdx /mnt/hdd
- If you have a separate boot partition mount that too.

  `mount -t ext2 /dev/sdx1 /mnt/hdd/boot`
- Now in order to have a functional chroot, we have to mount proc, dev and sys subsystems :

  ```
  mount -t proc none /mnt/hdd/proc
  mount -o bind /dev /mnt/hdd/dev
  mount -o bind /sys /mnt/hdd/sys
  ```
- We need to have internet acces :

  ```
  cp /etc/resolv.conf  /mnt/hdd/etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Use `chroot /mnt/hdd /bin/bash` to start a chrooted bash
- Install your package via apt
- Try to reboot

Comment: this needs more details!

Comment: You can also install the .deb package (if you can get it) locally if you don't have internet / repository access via `dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE`

Comment: Yeah but if the package have some external dependencies it will fail

Comment: Well, `firmware-linux-nonfree` hasn't, hence the addition to your answer.

Comment: recovery mode is not going to help if the drivers are needed for a disk controller. the OP explicitly states that he can only boot from a live CD.

Comment: I've added another technique

Answer (score 0):

As for now i don't have enough reputations to add a commend to @P0pR0cK5's answer, so I'll just append that if `chroot` from the previous answer did halt while trying to execute `chroot /mnt/hdd /bin/bash` resulting in the error `failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`, bind mounting additional directories would help.

```
sudo mount -o bind /usr /mnt/hdd/usr
sudo mount -o bind /lib /mnt/hdd/lib
sudo mount -o bind /lib64 /mnt/hdd/lib64
```

Finally, issue the `chroot /mnt/hdd /bin/bash` command back again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/502123)

Comment: @djdomi i just thought pinpointing the solution to this seemingly inevitable error when issuing chroot at the process would collectively help

Comment: then update the answers that it resolve the issue and add your additional information to the answer but dont use an answer to comment